# Unable to open WD external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

I have a 500 GB WD external drive with 3 partitions on it. When I run a disk check, the computer shuts down. After that, I can't access the single partition I have important data on. When I try to check the disk, it displays the following message:

> Disk check could not be performed because Windows cannot access disk

When I use the command line it gives some error message, and when I try to list the contents of the drive using the `dir` command it shows me an error message about "cyclic redundancy". The other partitions work fine.

What should I do? At least I want to be able to back up my data.

Comment: What tool are you using to do "disk error analysis"?

Comment: Have you tried to mount on a Linux computer or Live CD?

Comment: Have you tried the WD data lifeguard utility - available from their site?

Answer (score 0):

Try this action with other PCs.if you give this error in other PCs you sure that your WD is damage.But maybe you can recover your info with other 3RD party App.remember that you can't recover 100% your information.And finally if you have a warranty go and repair or change it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to open the external hard disk, then its time to do some recovery. First of all, save whatever the data is inside in some other medium rather than corrupted hard disk and then perform any task on it. So you need the software to get all your data retrieved from the disk. To do so you can try one of the software tool mentioned here to do [external hard drive recovery Windows 7](http://www.externaldriverecovery.com/windows-7.html). Later you can see whether the error is hardware error or logical error and steps accordingly.

Comment: Please don't use greetings and signature lines in posts. It adds unnecessary clutter.